# pg_upgrade fails with lc_ctype cluster values do not match

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, upgrade, postgresql-9.2

I'm upgrading my PostgreSQL version 9.1.4 database to version 9.2.4. Both the old and the new version are the bundled versions of [postgresapp.com](http://postgresapp.com) for Mac OS X.

When trying to upgrade the database I get this error:

```
# pg_upgrade -b /tmp/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin \
-B /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin \
-d var-9.1 \
-D var

Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking current, bin, and data directories                 ok
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is a superuser                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* system OID user data types                ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Creating catalog dump                                       ok

lc_ctype cluster values do not match:  old "de_DE", new "de_DE.UTF-8"
Failure, exiting
```

I searched this error message and found no useful tip to fix this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to re-initdb the new database with `LC_CTYPE` set to `de_DE` (i.e. use a non-Unicode encoding); check the old DB's encoding and use the same one when you initdb the new database.

Alternately, use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to do a dump and reload of the old DB's contents into the new DB. This requires that you have the old DB running.